# Retrieve substrings based on Pandas Dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have the following Pandas dfs:

```
print(df)

text_description     
ROME AND MILAN ARE AMAZING CITIES
NEW YORK AND LONDON REPRESENT GLOBAL FINANCE MARKETS
I LOVE MADRID 
BANGKOK IS AN AMAZING CITY
VAL D'ISERE IS A MAGIC PLACE

...


print(df_1)

City_List

PARIS
MILAN
ROME
NEW YORK
LONDON
MADRID
V. D'ISERE
```

I would like to filter out text from df["text_description"] and keep only city names contained in df_1["City_List"], obtaining two separate columns:

```
print(final_df)

text_description_0     text_description_1
ROME                          MILAN
NEW YORK                     LONDON
MADRID                         na
VAL D'ISERE                    na
...
```

How can I create "final_df"?

Comment: Will there be only 2 city names in a row always?

Comment: Max 2; the idea is to extract the city name from the string independently

Answer (score 0):

You won't get VAL D'ISERE, because it does not exactly exist in the city list. There is an abbreviation, but the program can't tell that. You would have to find a way to account for abbreviations. The code below only deals with exact words found in both columns :

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
#create a cross Cartesian of the two columns
#and keep only values where City list can be found in text description
for first,last in product(df1.text_description,df2.City_List):
    if last in first:
        d[first].append(last)

d = {k:','.join(v) for k,v in d.items()}

#map the dictionary to text description and create two columns
df1[['city1','city2']] = df1.text_description.map(d).str.split(',',expand=True)

df1
         text_description                               city1       city2
0   ROME AND MILAN ARE AMAZING CITIES                   MILAN       ROME
1   NEW YORK AND LONDON REPRESENT GLOBAL FINANCE M...   NEW YORK    LONDON
2   I LOVE MADRID                                       MADRID      None
3   BANGKOK IS AN AMAZING CITY                          NaN         NaN
4   VAL D'ISERE IS A MAGIC PLACE                        NaN         NaN
```